# Origin of "world-weary"

Tags: meaning, etymology

As a non native speaker, I thought that the words **world weary** referred to someone who carries the world on his/her shoulder or someone who wears/puts on the world. Then I noticed that the word weary has a different meaning. Is there any relationship between *wear* and *weary* in this context? Is there anyone who is able to explain the etymology of this phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always thought the usage *world-weary* was derived from the story of [Atlas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_%28mythology%29). Atlas is described as *Atlas Telamon* (Atlas the Enduring) and also as "[The world-weary Atlas](http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/R3EVTM10PLPWZV)" when Hercules encounters him during his quest for [The Apples of the Hesperides](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/Herakles/apples.html).(I couldn't find the Homeric greek for "the world-weary Atlas.")

Comment: It's a nice visualization, and may indeed be the source of the phrase, but I doubt the Greek etymology for the words "to wear" and "weary" is any closer than the English. The query seems to imply the words themselves are related.

Comment: You're right, the two words are distinct. Maybe I was taking the question too literally- OP asks if there is a relation between wear and weary "in this context*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak : I'll be happy to post my reply as a comment if that will be better.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, but I could not remember the example of Atlas. I am glad that you mentioned about it. So in this context, there is a relationship :)

Answer (score 3):

Though the words look similar, they are not related in the way you'd thought. Their pronunciations are different, too.

**To wear** is pronounced [wair] and [is derived](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wear) from O.E. *werian*, meaning "to clothe, put on".

**Weary** is pronounced [weer-ee] and [comes from](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=weary) O.E. *werig*, meaning "tired".

World-weary has nothing to do, literally, with the act of wearing or carrying anything; as a mnemonic device, though, that may be a helpful way to think of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the words of the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), ‘world-weary’ means ‘Weary of the world; feeling or indicating feelings of weariness, boredom, or cynicism as a result of long experience of life.’ Its first recorded use is in 1750.

The ‘weary’ element takes its sense from the OED’s second main definition of the adjective: ‘Discontented at the continuance or continued recurrence of something, and desiring its cessation; having one's patience, tolerance, zeal, or energy exhausted; “sick and tired” of something.’

Comment: I am afraid something is missing in my question. I know the definition of the phrase, however I am looking for a relationship between wear and weary. It seemed to me that a world weary person could be someone who carried the world, so that could be reason why she is unhappy about the life.

Comment: No, I don’t think that’s it. As I said, it derives from ‘weary’ meaning ‘discontented’, etc. Nothing to do with ‘wear’ as in ‘wearing clothes’. That has a quite different etymology.